# Passing dynamic information between AJAX generated modals

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I use a lot of modals in my application. Many times I need to pass information from one "box" to another.

**Example:** Say I have a table that lists car manufacturers (Audi, BMW, Honda, etc). Now I want to make it so each row is clickable. When a row is clicked a modal pops up with a table of the models they produce (Honda Accord, Civic, CR-V, etc).

Would this best be solved as follows:

```
<tr onclick="someAjaxFunction('manufacturerId')">
     <td>Audi</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="someAjaxFunction('manufacturerId')">
     <td>BMW</td>
</tr>
```

Now to layer on a layer of difficulty. Say that in the box that pops up there was a button that says "Add Model". You click that and now the box refreshes to show you a form where you type in a new car model. You click save, and now the box refreshes to show you that model list now with the new item listed.

Now lets say that we only want users with certain permissions to be allowed to add new models. Now the modal popup becomes more dynamic because it has to determine whether the user should see the "Add New" button or not. Would that mean that we would need to pass along the user's id from one box to the next and back?

```
<tr onclick="someAjaxFunction('manufacturerId', 'userId')">
     <td>Audi</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="someAjaxFunction('manufacturerId', 'userId')">
     <td>BMW</td>
</tr>
```

But now a tech savvy person could simply change the userId in the onclick event and would be able to do things they shouldn't.

**Question:** How do you keep passing dynamic information back and forth between the different modal screens? Do you do the same thing as above by creating more and more JavaScript functions that take various parameters and put them in onclick events?

*(No jquery please.)*

Comment: You need to use session variables on the server to keep track of the user ID, not send it from the browser.

Comment: Instead of passing lots of arguments in the function, you might try using an object, so you can refer to the options by property names instead of long lists of positional parameters. Or make use of `data-XXX` attributes to hold the details of each object, and pass `this` as the only argument.

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep track if the visitor is logged in or not with a php session variable and output the add button depending on that.

for example:

```
if($_session('is_user'){
   echo 'this is a add car model button';
}
else{
   echo 'log in to add a car model';
}
```

you could also keep the user id in a session variable so you don't have to pass it back and forth between client and server.